# Hashicorp Vault How Do I Login Headless From STDIN Using Bash Shell?

Tags: bash, authentication, headless, devops, vault

Given a Bash Shell say in a Docker container running on Gitlab, for example, how would I get the password to get passed in?

When I login with this:

```
 $ vault login -method=ldap username=myusername
```

It asks me for a password.

How do I get the prompt to not stop and for the password to be passed in as a variable?

I plan on using Gitlab Variables to pass in my password.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using JWT (JSON Web Token) [mutual authentication](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/authenticating-with-hashicorp-vault/) between Gitlab and Vault. This way there's no need to save any passwords anywhere (including variables), that is you first obtain a temporary Vault token via JWT Auth like this:

```
export VAULT_TOKEN="$(vault write -field=token auth/jwt/login role=builder jwt=$CI_JOB_JWT)"
```

And then you can access necessary secrets like this:

```
export VCENTER_USER="$(vault kv get -field=username /kv/builder/vcenter-auth)"
export VCENTER_PASSWORD="$(vault kv get -field=password /kv/builder/vcenter-auth)"
```

And when finished you can revoke this temporary token by:

```
vault token revoke -self
```

Answer (score 0):

As the author has explicitely asked for the userpass method I suggest as an answer to do it like this:

```
vault login -method=userpass username=myusername password=$userpass
```

where $userpass is your gitlab variable.

According to the official help of the CLI utility `vault auth help userpass`
there is no option like what you might be familiar with from other tools, e.g. `echo $password | docker login ghcr.io -u myusername --password-stdin`